# website event listener(?) to change image from url post

Tags: javascript, web, event-handling, addeventlistener

I would like to proof-of-concept something like the following: POST a message with a file name in it to my website (this POST could be from many types of devices, and from anywhere). My website 'gets' the message and loads the file that matches the incoming filename. It keeps 'listening' so that I can continue to pass filename strings for other images to load.

For the test, I will just be displaying jpegs in the website (assume all of the images would already exist on my website).

Code solution would be GREAT, but knowing that can be greedy - what are the terms I should be looking for to accomplish this so that I may Google and cobble together something?

Comment: You should be looking up AJAX tutorials for sending the requests to the server to get the images. You'll also need to write a little bit on the server back-end to make sure it receives the GET correctly from the client and is able to send the image back as requested.

Comment: Thanks! I will start to look. If I finish it I will come back and add.